# Adding group + items in Windows Explorer's pop-up menu?

Tags: windows, context-menu

An application I use regularly is command-line based, and I would like to add the most used commands in the Windows Explorer's context menu that pops up when right-clicking on a file or folder.

[image]

From what I read, a lot of programs in that menu are COM applications.

Is there an easier way to add commands to the menu, as an alternative to opening a DOS box and typing commands? Ideally, it should work for XP, Vista, and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Described in article](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/08/15/add-custom-items-to-windows-explorer-context-menu/) Fast Explorer do it. Verified.

Comment: Fast Explorer does work to add a group + items, but I'd like to send this to someone and there's no trace of those in the Registry. Does someone know how Fast Explorer saves data?

Comment: Registry, i can try to recall path

Comment: I searched through the Registry for a couple of items I created, but nothing turned up :-/

Comment: I found added keys under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers` (XP, if it matter)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did look there, but the menu + items I created with Fast Explorer aren't there, or anywhere else in the Registry. BTW, the data I added are used when right-clicking on a folder, not a file.

Comment: Will answer "it works for me" satisfy you?! I don't know why I get what I get - I just found and try Fast Explorer. I can run rest-case, show screenshot and registry-export, but I  can't grok *your* system, sorry - I'm not shaman

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1585/discussion-between-lazy-badger-and-overtherainbow)

Comment: Thanks but I seem to have found the cause: Fast Explorer creates items on the fly when checking its "Enable Dynamic Items". I'll read up and see if I can build a menu + items like 7-zip by hand and without COM.